# Wordpress Theme (JVPress) Header Graphic Won't Display in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site (www.nurseresumetips.com) and I'm using a theme named JVPress. 
This theme lets you to upload a custom header graphic. If you open the page in Firefox the header graphic displays, however when I open it in Internet Explorer 8 the image is not found.

The link that Wordpress is generating is: http://www.nurseresumetips.com/wp-content/uploads/20110419033853_nrt.jpg

This link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.

I just want to know if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Odd! It really does look like IE just can't read that JPEG. How are you creating the graphic? (And as a workaround, can you try saving it as a PNG rather than a JPEG, and see if that works? The image content is more suitable for a PNG, anyway, so it might even look better and be a smaller file...) Doesn't look like it's got anything to do with the site; IE can't even display that file from the local filesystem, for me.

Comment: Having looked around, I think you may be tripping over [a problem like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469/ie6-cant-load-a-normal-jpg), where your JPEG is encoded in a fairly specific format that IE and older versions of Firefox can't read.

Comment: Matt Thanks for the feedback. Please post an answer so I can upvote you.

Comment: @codingguy3000 Done. Is it working for you now, by the way?

Comment: I'm 90% sure that you have identified the reason. When I get home and put the kids to bed I'm got to check. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok the problem is that my jpg was using CMYK color. Internet Explorer will not display jpg files using CMYK. I converted the image to RGB and the issue is fixed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked around, I think you may be tripping over [a problem like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469/ie6-cant-load-a-normal-jpg), where your JPEG is encoded in a slightly odd format. Looks like CMYK is accepted as a format by some browsers, but not others.

Depending on your software, you might be able to find a way of saving in a more usual colour encoding -- in Photoshop, for example, try the specific "save for web" option.

Given the content of your image, I'd actually suggest saving the file as a PNG, anyway. JPEG is best for photographic images; for textual images like this one, PNG will probably (a) be more efficient, (b) look better -- no encoding artefacts around the nice solid lines you have, and (c) not have this odd problem you're facing.

Comment: Ok the problem is that my jpg was using CMYK color. Internet Explorer will not display jpg files using CMYK. I converted the image to RGB and the issue is fixed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.